# A controller with this name is not registered in Angulaj Js with Sql Database

Tags: c#, angularjs, entity-framework, linq, wcf

I am currently learning Angular Js . I added the ADO.NET Entitly model in my project and Angular Js Packages as well. I am unable to do insert like user registration from my registration page. I lunch the developer tools and its showing following error ...

```
Module.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at Module.js:5
    at Module.js:60
user.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
load.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
angular.min.js:42 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

Here is my Code in Module.js file under MyScript Folder..

```
var app;

(function () {
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

    app.controller("Ctrl", ['$scope', function ($scope){

        $scope.SaveUser = function () {
            $("#divLoading").show();
            var User = {
                FName: $scope.fName,
                LName: $scope.lName,
                Email: $scope.uEmail,
                Password: $scope.uPwd,
                UserName: $scope.uName
            };

            var response = myService.AddUser(User);
            response.then(function (data) {
                if (data.data == "1") {
                    $("#divLoading").hide();
                    clearFields();
                    alert("User Created !");
                    window.location.href = "/Register/Login";
                }
                else if (data.data == "-1") {
                    $("#divLoading").hide();
                    alert("user alraedy present !");
                }
                else {
                    $("#divLoading").hide();
                    clearFields();
                    alert("Invalid data entered !");
                }
            });
        }

        function clearFields() {
            $scope.fName = "";
            $scope.lName = "";
            $scope.Email = "";
            $scope.Password = "";
            $scope.UserName = "";
        }

    }]);
    app.service("myService", function ($http) {

        this.AddUser = function (User) {
            var response = $http({
                method: "post",
                url: "/Register/AddUser",
                data: JSON.stringify(User),
                dataType: "json"
            });
            return response;
        }
    })
})();
```

Here is my code in controller.The name of my controller is RegisterController  ..

```
public class RegisterController : Controller
        {
            public ActionResult Register()
            {
                return View();
            }

            //To check that user entered is already present or not.  
            public bool CheckUser(string user)
            {
                bool Exists = false;
                using (HalifaxDatabaseEntities context = new HalifaxDatabaseEntities())
                {
                    var uName = context.UserLogins.Where(x => x.UserName == user).ToList();
                    if (uName.Count != 0)
                    {
                        Exists = true;
                    }
                }
                return Exists;
            }

            //For saving the user details in database table.          
            public string AddUser(UserLogin usr)
            {
                if (usr != null)
                {
                    if (CheckUser(usr.UserName) == false)
                    {
                        using (HalifaxDatabaseEntities context = new HalifaxDatabaseEntities())
                        {
                            UserLogin createUser = new UserLogin();
                            createUser.UserName = usr.UserName;
                            createUser.Firstname = usr.Firstname;
                            createUser.Lastname = usr.Lastname;
                            createUser.Email = usr.Email;
                            createUser.DateTimeCreated = DateTime.Now;
                            createUser.Password = Utility.Encryptpassword(usr.Password);
                            context.UserLogins.Add(createUser);
                            context.SaveChanges();
                        }
                        return "User created !";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return "User already present !";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return "Invalid Data !";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is HTML CODE ...

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}


<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Register</title>

    <script src="~/Scripts/MyScript/Module.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container" ng-controller="myCntrl">
        <br />

        <div class="row">
            <img src="~/Content/Images/user.png" /><h4>Register User</h4>
            <hr />

            <br />
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <form name="userForm" novalidate>
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-left: 15px; color: #5bc0de;">
                                    First Name :
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="fName" ng-model="fName" required autofocus />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-left: 15px; color: #5bc0de;">
                                    Last Name :
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="lName" ng-model="lName" required autofocus />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-left: 15px; color: #5bc0de">
                                    Email :
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="User's Email" name="uEmail" ng-model="uEmail" required autofocus />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-left: 15px; color: #5bc0de;">
                                    Username :
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="uName" ng-model="uName" required autofocus />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-left: 15px; color: #5bc0de;">
                                    Password :
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="uPwd" ng-model="uPwd" required autofocus />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <input type="button" value="Save" ng-click="SaveUser();" class="btn btn-success" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Sign in", "Login", "Register", new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div id="divLoading" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: fixed; right: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #666666; z-index: 30001; opacity: .8; filter: alpha(opacity=70); display: none">
                                        <p style="position: absolute; top: 30%; left: 45%; color: White;">
                                            please wait...<img src="~/Content/images/load.png">
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is Screen Shot when I run the application [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yeg7a.png) ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yeg7a.png)

Any one help me to solved this Error [image: here new screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the first `var app;`

It is like you are declaring the app twice, try this

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
   .controller('myCntrl',['$scope',function($scope){
         // your code here
       }])
   .service();
```

**UPDATE**

In the *Module.js*, you have defined the name of your controller `app.controller("Ctrl",)`, but in the html File when you're calling it, you wrote `ng-controller='myCntrl'`

You have to give them the same name, that's it